# Makefile: 1037: recipe for target '../src/ap/beacon.o' failed

Tags: kali-linux, patch, hostapd

I am installing hosatpd-wpe as on kali linux rolling 2017.2 follows:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng/master/patches/wpe/hostapd-wpe/hostapd-wpe.patch 
wget https://w1.fi/releases/hostapd-2.9.tar.gz 
tar -zxf hostapd-2.9.tar.gz 
cd hostapd-2.9 patch -p1 < ../hostapd-wpe.patch 
cd hostapd

root@kali:/hostapd-2.6/hostapd# make
```

After typed `make` I received the following error message:

```
../src/ap/beacon.c: In function 'handle_probe_req':
../src/ap/beacon.c: 820:9:error: 'wpe_conf' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'wps_config'?
    If (wpe_conf.wpe_enable_karma && elems.ssid_len < 0) {
        Wpe_config
../src/ap/beacon.c:820:9:note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile: 1037: recipe for target '../src/ap/beacon.o' failed
Make: *** [../src/ap/beacon.o] Error 1
```

Could you please let me know how to fix the problem?? kindly be informed that I am a Network engineer, Not a programmer, so I need an easy way to solve it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier just to follow the instructions at https://www.kali.org/tools/hostapd-wpe/ and install the prebuilt package

```
apt update
apt install hostapd-wpe
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; but I would highly appreciate it , if you could also recommend a solution for the above, such as typing a certain command.

Comment: @Zac I've told you how to solve the problem, which is described as "_I am installing hosatpd-wpe as on kali linux_" and also later that "_I am a Network engineer, Not a programmer, so I need an easy way to solve it_". This is what I've done for you